# Why do I keep getting Error in sign(out$vectors[, 8]) : unimplemented complex function when I run my Rcode?

Tags: r

For reference purposes I will state the problem I am doing along with my RCode.

Problem:  Spectral clustering (partitioning) of a network (Network Classification). Consider the network shown in the figure Write the adjacency, degree and Laplacian matrices for this network, calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Laplacian matrix. The eigenvector corresponding to the second smallest eigenvalue can be used to partition the network into two groups. What are these two groups?
[Image for the problem I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwNh0.jpg)

Here is my Rcode to solve the problem:

```
'''{r, echo = T}
# list your R codes here!
A <- matrix(
  c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    1/2,0,0,0,0,0,1/2,0,0,
    0,0,1/2,0,0,0,1/2,0,0,
    0,1/2,0,0,0,1/2,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,
    0,1/2,0,0,1/2,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,1/2,0,0,0,1/2,0,0),
  nrow = 9,
  ncol = 9,
  byrow = TRUE)

D<- diag(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1))
D

L<- D-A
L

out<- eigen(L)
sign(out$vectors[,8])

'''
```

Everytime I run my code it gives me this error: Error in sign(out$vectors[, 8]) : unimplemented complex function

I'm not sure how to fix it, can someone please help me?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788164/positive-and-negative-complex-numbers. I'm not a pure-enough mathematician to weigh in with a theoretical resolution to this, but ... `out` is not *real*, it is `complex`, so "sign" of such is a little more complicated?

Comment: I am not understanding your help. Can you explain what the problem is with the statement that I keep getting an error about and/or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Look at `out$vectors`. It is not "real", it is a matrix of "complex" numbers (as in `i = sqrt(-1)`). The function `sign` and, related in that post I linked, the *concept* of positivity/negativity with complex numbers is not as clear as for real numbers. As a clearer demonstration, see that `as.complex(0)` is `0+0i` (complex) but `as.complex(0) > as.complex(1)` is an invalid comparison.  If you are expecting all real numbers in your output, then perhaps your data is wrong/corrupt or the process leading up to `eigen(.)` is missing something.